# Error installing mongo db on ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS

Tags: node.js, linux, mongodb, ubuntu, failed-installation

I have tried purging and reinstalling mongo db several times but I continuously get the following error when installing. It seems like the problem comes in when trying to install additional packages and trying to remove mogodb, mongodb-clients, and mongodb-server:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  mongodb-org-database-tools-extra mongodb-org-mongos mongodb-org-server mongodb-org-shell mongodb-org-tools
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  mongodb mongodb-clients mongodb-server
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  mongodb-org mongodb-org-database-tools-extra mongodb-org-mongos mongodb-org-server mongodb-org-shell mongodb-org-tools
0 upgraded, 6 newly installed, 3 to remove and 23 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/49.8 MB of archives.
After this operation, 124 MB of additional disk space will be used.
(Reading database ... 268876 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing mongodb (1:3.6.9+really3.6.8+90~g8e540c0b6d-0ubuntu5) ...
Removing mongodb-server (1:3.6.9+really3.6.8+90~g8e540c0b6d-0ubuntu5) ...
Removing mongodb-clients (1:3.6.9+really3.6.8+90~g8e540c0b6d-0ubuntu5) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mongodb-org-shell.
(Reading database ... 268856 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../0-mongodb-org-shell_4.4.6_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mongodb-org-shell (4.4.6) ...
Preparing to unpack .../1-mongodb-org-server_4.4.6_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mongodb-org-server (4.4.6) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-i8t6ED/1-mongodb-org-server_4.4.6_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/mongod', which is also in package mongodb-server-core 1:3.6.9+really3.6.8+90~g8e540c0b6d-0ubuntu5
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Preparing to unpack .../2-mongodb-org-mongos_4.4.6_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mongodb-org-mongos (4.4.6) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-i8t6ED/2-mongodb-org-mongos_4.4.6_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/mongos', which is also in package mongodb-server-core 1:3.6.9+really3.6.8+90~g8e540c0b6d-0ubuntu5
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Selecting previously unselected package mongodb-org-database-tools-extra.
Preparing to unpack .../3-mongodb-org-database-tools-extra_4.4.6_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mongodb-org-database-tools-extra (4.4.6) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mongodb-org-tools.
Preparing to unpack .../4-mongodb-org-tools_4.4.6_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mongodb-org-tools (4.4.6) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mongodb-org.
Preparing to unpack .../5-mongodb-org_4.4.6_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mongodb-org (4.4.6) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-i8t6ED/1-mongodb-org-server_4.4.6_amd64.deb
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-i8t6ED/2-mongodb-org-mongos_4.4.6_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

If I try to fix the problem using

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install
```

I get these errors again:

```
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/mongodb-org-server_4.4.6_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/mongod', which is also in package mongodb-server-core 1:3.6.9+really3.6.8+90~g8e540c0b6d-0ubuntu5
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Preparing to unpack .../mongodb-org-mongos_4.4.6_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mongodb-org-mongos (4.4.6) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/mongodb-org-mongos_4.4.6_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/mongos', which is also in package mongodb-server-core 1:3.6.9+really3.6.8+90~g8e540c0b6d-0ubuntu5
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/mongodb-org-server_4.4.6_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/mongodb-org-mongos_4.4.6_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

additional information:

```
 mongodb-org : Depends: mongodb-org-server but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: mongodb-org-mongos but it is not going to be installed
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like other attempts to purge mongodb from my computer were insufficient, but I found this solution:

```
sudo apt remove mongodb
sudo apt purge mongodb
sudo apt autoremove
```

this removed all instances of mongodb and reinstalling it produced no errors